# How do I change UITextField border from itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have `MYTextField` inherited from `UITextField`.

I call `[self changeBorderColor]` method inside `MYTextField` that looks like that:

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([UIColor brownColor]);
self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

But nothing happen. Is there way to do that?

Comment: what is self? you must use as self.myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1& so on..

Comment: try self.setNeedsDisplay() after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of `self.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([UIColor brownColor]);`

write `self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor brownColor].CGColor;`

Answer (score 0):

By using the layer property you can do like this way,

```
tf.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0f;
tf.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
tf.layer.borderColor = [UIColor brownColor].CGColor;
tf.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
```